# Why will IE & Chrome show this image but Firefox wont?

Tags: html, firefox

Here is the simple HTML

```
<html>
<head><head>
<body>
<img src='\\{NETWORK_FILE_SHARE_PATH}\pic_pipeline1.jpg' title='pipePic' height='24' alt='alt-image'/>
</body>
</html>
```

I view this html file in IE10 and Chrome Version 39.0.2171.65 and I can see the image. But if I open it with FireFox 33.1 all I see are the words "alt-image"

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is sandboxing possible malicious content.

If it is not a `file://` url, the browser should not allow access to the filesystem for *any* purpose.

One possible misuse would be to load local images and upload them without your consent.